# Split cost of bringing 1 kg to LEO

Tags: low-earth-orbit, cost, logistics

Historically seen, space logistics prices decrease, as [shown here](https://www.quora.com/Rockets-What-is-cost-of-sending-1-kg-weight-into-space), from $20K/kg to expected 1.7K/kg thanks to reusable rockets.

But, how does the cost split look like and vary in detail? i.e. "fuel - 40%, shipment fee - 25%, ..."

If possible, let's compare SpaceX with BlueOrigin. I try to get a rough idea however.

Comment: Nice question !

Comment: I feel this will vary a lot between different launch providers. Could you ask about one provider in particular to make the question easier to answer rigorously?

Comment: if data is available @Jack it'd surely nice to compare two of them; added to example

Comment: Remember that *cost* is not *price*.

Comment: One line item to help start an answer: According to wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9 the fuel cost for a Falcon 9 is around \$200,000, i.e. something of the order \$10/kg. In other words, the cost of fuel is not a significant contributer to the total.